# Find a counterexample to the following lemma if we change the statement slightly.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

let K be an algebraic number field and let $O_K$ be its ring of integers.

Lemma; Let $a,b$ be fractional ideals of $O_K$. If $b \subseteq a$ then there is an ideal $c$ such that $b=ac$.

I need to find a counterexample for why this fails for general orders $R$ in our number field in particular a counterexample for $K=Q(\sqrt{-3})$ and $R=Z[\sqrt{-3}]$.

I am confused as to what I should be looking for and am finding it hard to attempt even though I imagine it is probably fairly easy. I am thinking that the most likely condition that goes missing which will help is the fact that a prime ideal in R is no longer necessarily maximal. If someone could help get a counterexample and explain why its true that would be great, thanks.

Comment: $R$ has dimension $1$, as it is an integral extension of $\Bbb{Z}$, and it is Noetherian. What fails here is being integrally closed.

Comment: Ok, I'm still super confused

Answer (score 1):

Barring a mistake the following should work. Based on using the fact that $(-1+\sqrt{-3})/2$ is missing.

Let $a=\langle 2,1+\sqrt{-3}\rangle$ and $b=\langle 1+\sqrt{-3}\rangle$.
Then
$$
a=\{x+y\sqrt{-3}\in R\mid x\equiv y\pmod 2\}
$$
and
$$
b=\{x+y\sqrt{-3}\in R\mid x\equiv y\pmod 4\}.
$$

**Claim 1.** $a$ is the only ideal properly between $b$ and $R$.

**Proof.** We see that $b$ is of index $4$ in $R$, a set of representative of cosets consisting of $\{0,1,2,3\}$. An ideal containing either $1$ or $3$ in addition to all the elements of $b$ will be all of $R$. The only alternative is to include $2$. But then we get $a$. Q.E.D.

**Claim 2.** There is no ideal $c$ such that $b=ac$.

**Proof.** Assume that such an ideal $c$ exists. Clearly $b\subseteq c$, so by Claim 1 we must have $c=a$. But as $(1+\sqrt{-3})^2=-2+2\sqrt{-3}$ we get
$$
a^2=\langle4,2+2\sqrt{-3},-2+2\sqrt{-3}\rangle.
$$
This is too small.

Comment: Sorry about some confusion initially. I need to rush. Hope it's correct now.